# How to catch touchBegan by other subviews such us UIScrollView

Tags: iphone

I have a UIScrollView in my view control but my UIScrollView can't catch the touchBegan. touchBegan only execute when touching outside of the UIScrollView. How can catch the touchBegan when touching UIScrollView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must subclass `UIScrollView` (or an other view) and re-implement the methods you want to catch. Don't forget to call super in you implementation!

Comment: What do you mean subclass UIScrollView? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to subclass UIScrollView, your *MyUIScrollView.h* file should look similar to this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MyUIScrollView : UIScrollView {

}

@end
```

Then, in your *MyUIScrollView.m*, you place your *touchesBegan* method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}
```

After you do this, anywhere in your code where you now use an *UIScrollView*, you switch to using a *MyUIScrollView*.